# CameraX in Texture View Gets inverted at 90 degrees in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have implemented CameraX using Texture View in my application. the problem that i am facing is that when i change the orientation from portrait to landscape, the camera gets inverted at 90 degrees and the preview is not showing correctly. . 
Can anyone please guide me how to set it up so that it shows correctly in the landscape mode too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this repo.There is no issues in rotation and preview. I have written CameraX in Java and it's working fine. Let me know if you need help.

https://github.com/arindamxd/android-camerax